# "buildozer android update" fails

Tags: android, python, git, kivy, buildozer

I have installed `kivy`(v:1.10.0) and `buildozer` on my mint.
I have my kivy app working fine.

I am following ["installing buildozer with python3 support"](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer#installing-buildozer-with-python3-support) to compile my apk file.

But I am facing error in step 5 while executing `buildozer android debug deploy run` in terminal.

The output is:

```
Check configuration tokens
Ensure build layout
Check configuration tokens
Preparing build
Check requirements for android
Install platform
Command failed: git clone -b stable --single-branch
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android-new-toolchain

Buildozer failed to execute the last command
If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
and retry the latest command.
In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That repository no longer include a branch name `stable`.

See the [list of branches here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/branches).

Try and modify that step using a different branch name: `master`.
Change it in [kivy/buildozer `/buildozer/default.spec`](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/94691c013814874d39499c5fc7024c0f4efba4f2/buildozer/default.spec#L152-L153)